# Выдается последний элемент списка

Tags: python, парсер, proxy, error404

Всем привет! у меня парсер прокси, и тут такая проблема что выдается последний элемент из списка
у меня 400 строчек и выдается только самая последняя, подскажите как решить
Код:

```
with open('https.txt', 'r') as proxy:
    linesstrok = proxy.readlines()
    for proxy in linesstrok:
        ip= proxy.split(':')[0]
        port = proxy.split(':')[1]

proxy= 'http://'+ ip + ":" + port
print(proxy)
```

Comment: Последние 2 строчки засунуть в тот же цикл `for`.

Comment: Вот что я получаю на выходе 

Atom Runner: test.py
Atom Runner: test.py
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611
http://184.82.235.92:611

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('https.txt', 'r') as proxy:
    linesstrok = proxy.readlines()
    for proxy in linesstrok:
        ip= proxy.split(':')[0]
        port = proxy.split(':')[1]
        proxy= 'http://'+ ip + ":" + port
        print(proxy)
```